# Custom control causes VS2010 to crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm sure this is a really simple question, so I apologize in advance if I annoy anyone by asking it. I've been trying to create my own custom control for use in an application, but whenever I try to add the new control to my form, Visual Studio 2010 crashes.

I'm sure there's something I should have at the beginning of the custom control that indicates it should appear in the toolbox. As of now, it only appears there when I add the project to the other app's solution. Is there something I'm missing? I'll be happy to post the code if necessary.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post the code as necessary, and the error you are getting.

Comment: Attach a debugger to VS and look at the exception.

Comment: Please note that anytime you have an error, you need to post it, also since you are crashing the IDE, it would be nice to get an overview of what your control does, the code for your constructor, whether or not you have any timers or processes happening that should be disabled during designmode and what framework you are using Winforms, Wpf, Asp.net ???

Comment: ReCreate a new project if possible or recreate your custom control

Comment: Also check the Application Log in the Event Viewer of Windows. It should contain at least one and probably two event that give more details on what caused the crash. Look for events named `Application Error` or `.NET Runtime`.